# jquery parse json array fails

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I have json array like this one:

```
[{"code" : "A1", "desc" : "desc1"},{"code" : "A2", "desc" : "desc2"}]
```

How should i parse it in jquery to get data like this:

```
A1 - desc1
A2 - desc2
```

I tried lots of different ways, but none of them works. At the moment i have a code like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my_url',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            alert(val.code);
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('problem');
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to use `$.parseJSON` on `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem. The problem was my hosting provider. I am using Codeigniter as a framework, and return result as json. My hosting provides adds 3 additional lines to the result (uses them for tracking opened pages). Problem was, that i was checking json, which i see in browser, but when i rightclicked and checked source code, i found those lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try setting the

`dataType:'json'`   // to your ajax request

After adding this try to check with parseJson and sans parseJson

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jQuery.parseJSON( json )
```

Change code to

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'my_url',
   success: function(data) {
      var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
        alert(val.code);
      });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('problem');
  }
});
```

EDIT: Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYmA9/)

Cheers!!

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work. Previously it alerted "undefined" and now i don't get any alert.

Comment: Mine is failing with $.parseJSON( data );